Manifest file is missing or unreadable Could not load manifest
Working on 1st chrome extension using WXT built tool. upon loading the .output file that is generated after the npm run build it shows me this "error Manifest file is missing or unreadable
Could not load manifest."
this is what my wxt.config.js looks like
import { defineConfig } from 'wxt';

// See https://wxt.dev/api/config.html
export default defineConfig({
  manifest:{
    manifest_version: 3,
    name: "LinkedIn Message Assistant",
    version: "1.0",
    description: "Generates LinkedIn messages for you.",
    action: {
      default_popup: "popup.html"
    },
    permissions: [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
    ],
    content_scripts: [
      {
        matches: ["https://www.linkedin.com/*"],
        js: ["src/contentScript.js"],
        css: ["src/styles.css"]
      }
    ]
  },
  modules: ['@wxt-dev/module-react'],
});

am i missing something here?
New with WXT any leads will be helpfull
